# Android Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clears SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences

I have an application with the following activity flow A->B->C. In activity C the user is presented with the option to save their username and data (a string and a string array converted to string) that I store in a SharedPreferences file and call Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. This brings them back to activity A. However when I try to check the stored username vs the one they enter now, I'm always presented with a NullPointerException.

```
private void saveData(){

    SharedPreferences session_data = getSharedPreferences("SESSION_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = session_data.edit();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        sb.append(myData[i]).append(",");
    }

    editor.putString("SAVED_SCAN",sb.toString());
    editor.putString("SAVED_ID",myID);
    Toast.makeText(C.this,"Data Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    endActivity();


}
private void endActivity(){
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then back in acitivty A.(textData is a EditText.getText().toString())

```
 SharedPreferences prf = getSharedPreferences("SESSION_DATA",MODE_PRIVATE);
 String testID = prf.getString("SAVED_ID",null);

 try {
       if(testID.equals(textData)){
             toast.makeText(A.this,"MATCH",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: You aren't saving data to `SharedPreferences`. Don't forget to call `editor.apply()`

Comment: Didn't the Android studio warned you that you are not using apply() and commit() methods. Normally Android studio shows a warning if you are not using any of those methods when initializing an SharePreference Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add data into the shared-preferences:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putString("name", "myname");
  editor.putInt("id", 12);
  editor.apply()
```

**Get data from the shared-preferences:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name= prefs.getString("name", "xyz"); // here xyz is the default value
int id = prefs.getInt("id", 0); // 0 is the default value.
```